# Mysql Check If other Rows have the same value based on result of another query

Tags: mysql

Good Day.
As an example i have a table with 2 fields refid and checksum

I would like to get all the refids where the checksum matches a specific ID

```
|refid|checksum|

|1    | abc

|2    | def

|3    | hij

|4    | def

|5    | hij
```

I then have the refid that i want to match. So if i have refid 2
I want to get all rows that match the checksum colum of the row that matches 2

In 2 queries i would do

```
Select Checksum FROM t1 WHERE refid = 2
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE checksum = <result of query 1>
```

I would like to do this in one query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can done this is in two ways

By **IN**

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE checksum IN
             (Select Checksum FROM t1 WHERE refid = 2)
```

Or:

By **LIMIT**

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE checksum =
             (Select Checksum FROM t1 WHERE refid = 2 Limit 1)
```